# After transforming a DataFrame into an array, 8x more memory is used. Why?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I want to use the StandardScaler on my DataFrame. The df currently has 303MB. After applying the StandardScaler, the DataFrame has become a numpy array - with size 2529MB. How is that posible? How do I solve this problem?

I just transformed it manually here and did not use the StandardScaler, but the result is the same. The computations are much longer with such a huge dataset. How can I solve this problem?

```
    X.info()

    <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
    RangeIndex: 150930 entries, 0 to 150929
    Columns: 2095 entries, len_description to winery_àMaurice
    dtypes: int32(1), int64(1), uint8(2093)
    memory usage: 303.0 MB

    np.array(X.values).nbytes/1e6

    2529.5868
```

Comment: Your array memory size is roughly 8 times that of the dataframe.  Most of your data within the dataframe has dtype unit8.  My guess is your numpy array has dtype float64 (or int64)...hence the 8x memory increase.

Comment: yes thats correct!

Comment: So in a word, you can't solve that problem. You can convert the data to float32 or float16.

Comment: As i have no floats in my data, can i convert to uint8? or would that harm my data?

Comment: @Phil, Depends on your data.. Why don't you try converting types in Pandas first, i.e. `X.apply(pd.to_numeric, downcast='integer').values.nbytes/1e6`. If Pandas can't downcast to `int8`, this indicates you have values somewhere which can't be held in `int8`.

Comment: @phil depending on the data you have. For large numbers it definitely will. Note that `uint8` can store values in the range -128 to 127

Comment: Does it make sense to get an array of the whole dataframe? Given the `dtypes`, the 3 columns (Series) must contain significantly different kinds of data.  Create 2 or 3 arrays rather than just one.

Comment: @yatu Not quite.  This is uint8 (unsigned 8-bit integer), so the range goes from 0 - 255.

Comment: True @tnknepp it is unsigned, thx for pointing out